# Set range limits on DateTimeItem

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

What I need specifically is to prevent user from entering date/time that is in the future. That's different than disabling a specific date, since I need to disable ALL dates part a certain date.

Ideally, any future dates should be disabled. For now, I'm just going prevent form submit when user enters invalid time, but disabling unwanted dates would be better.

I went through the javadoc and found nothing. Is it possible? How?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957705/gwt-datebox-disable-specific-date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GWT DateBox - Disable specific date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957705/gwt-datebox-disable-specific-date)

Comment: @IgnacioBaca That question is about disabling one date. I need to disable all dates since certain date.

Comment: Is the same, just move through the range and set each day as disabled. I'll try to answer with an example later 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuring a range just means disabling the dates outside this range. So the process is the same as the one in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957705/gwt-datebox-disable-specific-date). You can create a utility method to create filters easier. For example, `configureShowRangeHandler` admits a `Predicate<Date>` that will disable the date if the predicate returns false. The `enableUntilToday` is a simple example to limit selectable dates until today.

```
{
    DatePicker dp = new DatePicker();
    Predicate<Date> enableUntilTodayDates = d -> !d.after(new Date());
    configureShowRangeHandler(dp, enableUntilTodayDates);
}

static HandlerRegistration configureShowRangeHandler(DatePicker dp, Predicate<Date> fn) {
    return dp.addShowRangeHandler(ev -> {
        for (Date t = copyDate(ev.getStart()); t.before(ev.getEnd()); addDaysToDate(t, 1)) {
            dp.setTransientEnabledOnDates(fn.test(t), t);
        }
    });
}
```

- `copyDate` and `addDaysToDate` are static imported from `CalendarUtil`